# Android - How can I check the sender class of the "stopService" Intent?

Tags: android, class, android-intent, service, ondestroy

I stop a service from various places. How can I check when the sender of the command "stopService(Intent intent)" was my NetworkReceivar class (extends BroadcastReceiver)??

This is my code for do this more clear:

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    boolean isNetworkDown = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
    if (isNetworkDown) {
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
    }
```

My service class:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "OnDestroy");
    // if came from NetworkReceiver do something.
    this.updater.interrupt();
    this.updater = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Right now, the way I am controlling this is using SharedPreferences and adding a boolean preference in the Broadcast that indicates me if the intent was launch by the NetworkReceiver or not.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check when the sender of the command "stopService(Intent intent)" was my NetworkReceivar class (extends BroadcastReceiver)??

AFAIK, you can't.

However, instead of `stopService()`, you could call `startService()`, sending over a command that your service interprets as "time to shut down". Something on that `Intent` that is your command could be used to indicate the sender, so that you can distinguish one sender from another. And, the service can call `stopSelf()` to shut itself down.

Comment: That's what I thought...
Well if there is no any other way I prefer the way I am doing it, using Shared Preferences.
Thank you!